# Understanding たは:

Tags: grammar, particles

I'm sure this has been covered, but searching for something as vague as たは has it's complications given た's usage as a verb ending.

My question comes from the たは use in the following.

> あなたが**たは**世の光です。
>
> (マタイ 5：14)

I'm not sure what to search for to find this grammatical construct: What's it called and what does it mean in this context?

ありがとうございまう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is あなた ("thou", second person pronoun) + [[方]{がた}](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%96%B9-2) (honorific pluralizing suffix) + は (topic particle).

Comment: AH! So it's not あなたが (topic) but something like: あなた方は.   I understand now, and  found this with no problem once you named it: https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/plural-suffix/
ありがとうございまう。